# To delete a lines containing only numbers and punctuation marks in a huge text file

Tags: linux

I am having things of this kind in my 5 million word Kannada text file:

```
, .
, , , .
, .
2005 .
, , 878 .
, .
2008 .
- , 751 .
- .
```

I need to delete lines of this kind.

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
sed -n  '/^[[:punct:][:digit:][:space:]]\+$/!p' file
sed     '/^[[:punct:][:digit:][:space:]]\+$/d' file
sed -nr '/^[[:punct:][:digit:][:space:]]+$/!p' file
sed -r  '/^[[:punct:][:digit:][:space:]]+$/d' file
```

Using awk:

```
awk '!/^[[:punct:][:digit:][:space:]]+$/' file
```

Another way is to just print lines with alpha chars on it:

```
awk '/[[:alpha:]]' file
awk '/[A-Za-z]/' file
sed -n '/[[:alpha:]]/p' file
sed '/[A-Za-z]/!d' file
```

Of course you may use sed with `-i` to do inline editing:

```
sed -i.bak ...
```

Forgot `grep`:

```
grep -v '^[[:punct:][:digit:][:space:]]\+$' file
grep '[[:alpha:]]' file
```